# How do I send and receive UDP packets in QT

Tags: qt, networking, udp

I am writing a small application in QT that sends a UDP packet broadcast over the local network and waits for a UDP responce packet from one or more devices over the network.

Creating the sockets and sending the broadcast packet.

```
udpSocketSend = new QUdpSocket(this);
udpSocketGet  = new QUdpSocket(this);
bcast = new QHostAddress("192.168.1.255");

udpSocketSend->connectToHost(*bcast,65001,QIODevice::ReadWrite);
udpSocketGet->bind(udpSocketSend->localPort());
connect(udpSocketGet,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));

QByteArray *datagram = makeNewDatagram(); // data from external function
udpSocketSend->write(*datagram);
```

The application sends the packet properly and the response packet arrives but the `readPendingDatagrams()` function is never called. I have verified the packets are sent and received using Wireshark and that the application is listening on the port indicated in wireshark using Process Explorer.

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem. Here is the solution.

```
udpSocketSend = new QUdpSocket(this);
udpSocketGet  = new QUdpSocket(this);
host  = new QHostAddress("192.168.1.101");
bcast = new QHostAddress("192.168.1.255");

udpSocketSend->connectToHost(*bcast,65001);
udpSocketGet->bind(*host, udpSocketSend->localPort());
connect(udpSocketGet,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));

QByteArray *datagram = makeNewDatagram(); // data from external function
udpSocketSend->write(*datagram);
```

The device on the network listens on port 65001 and responds to packets on the source port of the received packet. It is necessary to use `connectToHost(...)` in order to know what port to bind for the response packet.

It is also necessary to bind to the correct **address** and port to receive the packets. This was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're binding your `udpSocketSend` in `QIODevice::ReadWrite` mode. So that's the object that's going to be receiving the datagrams.

Try one of:

- binding the send socket in write only mode, and the receive one in receive only mode
- using the same socket for both purposes (remove `udpSocketGet` entirely).

depending on your constraints.

Comment: Neither solution worked. Using udpSocketSend->bind(udpSocketSend->localPort()) and connect(udpSocketSend,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readPendingDatagrams())) doesn't trigger readPendingDatagrams(). Also configuring udpSocketSend with QIODevice::WriteOnly and doesn't trigger readPendingDatagrams(). Since this is UDP the connectToHost(...) method does not bind to a port, it just sets up the udpSocketSend so it can use udpSocketSend->write(*datagram) instead of udpSocketSend->writeDatagram(...) which is not recommended to be used on a connected socket.

Answer (score 1):

For me, changing the bind from

```
udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 45454);
```

to simple

```
udpSocket->bind(45454);
```

does the trick!