# How do I send and receive UDP packets in QT through a router

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, udp

I have a program that sends and receives broadcast messages. If I run two copies of these programs on the same PC, everything works just fine. If I run each copy on different PCs, then the broadcast messages are not received. I utilized Wireshark to verify whether the packets were sent (yes they were). In addition, on PC "A" Wireshark does not observe the sent packets, but on PC "B" everything is OK. Could the problem be in hardware?

Receiver code:

```
Receiver::Receiver(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(45454, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->start(500);

    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));
}

void Receiver::processPendingDatagrams()
{
    qDebug("first entrance");

    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());

        qDebug() << datagram.data();
        qDebug("Receive");

        sendToQML(datagram.data());
    }

}
```

Sender code:

```
Sender::Sender(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    messageNo  = 0;
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
}

void Sender::broadcastDatagram(int message)
{
    QByteArray datagram = QByteArray::number(message);
    udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                             QHostAddress::Broadcast, 45454);
}

void Sender::sendBroadcast(int message)
{
    qDebug() << message;

    broadcastDatagram(message);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to send and receive packets through an ethernet connection (via a cable).

Comment: Broadcasts are not normally transmitted between different networks. Your router needs to be able to handle it, and if it does then you need to configure it to handle it.

Comment: @Some programmer dude can you please point out which settings should I set?

Comment: You need to read the documentation for *your specific* router.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you

Comment: To talk to another host you need to go through IP not localhost port: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515589/how-do-i-send-and-receive-udp-packets-in-qt when the datagram reaches the other computer then it  needs port.

Comment: @AlexanderVX yeah I saw that.  Decided to apply another approach by using nginx.

Comment: I meant that the problem is purely with understanding how UDP works and even has nothing to do with specifics of a router.

Comment: @AlexanderVX maybe you are correct. I know I have to learn much more about UDP mechanism. Anyway I managed to solve my problem. Thank you.